# different behaviour of unhashable typeError between cpp and python

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

It is ok to insert a `vector` to a `set` in cpp, which not works in python however. Codes shown below:

```
// OK in cpp
set<vector<int>> cpp_set;
cpp_set.insert(vector<int>{1,2,3});

// not OK in python
py_set = set()
py_set.add([1,2,3])  # TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
py_set.add({1,2,3})  # TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Even adding a set to a set is not allowed, and I don't understand why a set is unhashable.

Why does the difference happens? And is it a permitted good way to use in cpp? I mean adding a vector to a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `set` is a hash table, and has no hashing functions for `set` and `list`.

`std::set` is not a hash table but a sequence ordered by an ordering relation (`std::less` by default).
You can use `std::set` with any type where you can define a [*strict weak ordering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).

Try `std::unordered_set` in C++ and you will encounter problems.

Comment: I think this misses the core of the problem. You can use set or unordered_set in C++ on pretty much every element type, including sets and vectors themselves. You have to provide a hashing function or a comparison function, but that's it. Or am I perhaps missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Elements of a container modeling a mathematical set should always be immutable, regardless of language, which is important for the guarantees/invariants that are typically associated with such a type. The difference between Python and C++ here is that Python requires an immutable type up front, while C++ just uses `const` to make one immutable.

Notes:

- The elements of a C++ `set<T>` are actually `T const`.
- Of course, C++ has `const_cast`, so it's not as immutable as it may seem.
- Storing an element in a `set` creates a copy. Modifying the original doesn't change the copy.
- For a C++ hash set (`std::unordered_set`), you have the additional requirement that you must be able to hash the elements. The hash of an element must remain the same over time as well, which is why it has similar limitations.